# Accept numbers from 0 to 60 but disallow leading zeros

Tags: html, regex

I am trying to write a `regex` to use in an `<input>` field, where numbers from 0 to 60 are accepted. This is the one I have now:

```
<input type="number" min="0" max="60" pattern="^([0-5]?[0-9]|60)$">
```

It works fine, but the issue is that inputs like `02` should not be validated. Do you know how to improve this expression?

Thanks in advance for your replies!

Comment: Use `type="text"`, otherwise the `pattern` will be ignored. You may also omit `^` and `$` in the pattern since HTML5 patterns are anchored by default. So, you want to disallow leading zeros, do you? Then use `<input type="text" pattern="[1-5]?[0-9]|60">`

Comment: 02 should not be validated ?

Comment: Why do you even disallow leading zeros? Just drop them serverside i.e. cast to an int, then they are gone automatically.

Comment: Almost there... remove the 0 from first pair of brackets i.e. `([1-5]?[0-9]|60)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

if you don't want to accept `02`, why you put such rule in your pattern?

correct one is: `^([1-5]?[0-9]|60)$`

also, as mentioned above in comments, `pattern` attribute doesn't work with `type=number` - use `text` instead (supported are: text, date, search, url, tel, email and password)

Comment: Thanks man! I have actually tried and even with `type="number"` it properly works

Answer (score 2):

```
<input type="text" min="0" max="60" pattern="^([1-5]?[0-9]|60)$">
```

Please note that this will also accept "0". Is that desired behavior?

Comment: `input type=number` doesn't allow pattern attribute

Comment: You're right. It should be type="text". I'll change it.